# how can i indicate parameter in Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I know  `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` can take user input but can I ask how to use it, whenever I put them, the netbeans just run through it without asking any user input in console, I just want to ask how to configure for using using user input?

of course, i put nextLine and nextInt, i just want to ask how to make netBeans stop and ask me the input.

Comment: You can just add a `sysout` just before the line where you are reading, to print the message

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will see something called `output` (window) in bottom --> There you will see prompt for input.

If output window is not available there, goto `Window menu--> Select output--> ouput`

(or) `Ctrl+4`

Comment: i KNOW that window, it just says:run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Not sure your code has prompt or not, if not you need to prompt for input, example System.out.println("Please enter some value: ");

Answer (score 0):

because you need to give a message before like this.

// this is your input object

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 // give massage 
System.out.println("give some in put");

 // to get input where you want
String input = input.nextline();

 system.out.println(""+input);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. Here is an example for you.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) [
        Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;

        System.out.print("Enter number: "); // This displays to the user to enter a number.
        i = INPUT.nextInt(); // Sets i equal to the user input.
    }
}
```

If you are using a string for input try INPUT.nextLine();.

You can find more info on it here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html